# Java JTextArea Line Numbers

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, line-numbers

I'm trying to add line numbers to a JTextArea and am having some difficulties. The line numbers appear, but they do not scroll properly.

I have a linked-list of a custom class that stores a line of data (log message) and a line number associated with it as well as visibility on whether it should be shown in the text area or not. So what I did was create two JTextAreas... one to store the logs, and the other to store the line numbers.

The layout works and the line numbers populate correctly with the logs. The problem is when I try to scroll up or down. The logs adjust properly as you scroll, but the line numbers do not. Nothing shows beyond the initial 28 line numbers that are shown initially. The space is just blank.

My code is below:

```
public class CustomLineNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{    
    ...
    private JTextArea logField;
    private JTextArea lineField;

    private List<Log> logs;

    public CustomLineNumbers() 
    {       
        ...
        logs = new ArrayList<Log>();

        logField = new JTextArea(28, 68);
        logField.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0));
        logField.setEditable(false);
        logField.setLineWrap(true);
        logField.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        lineField = new JTextArea();
        lineField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 0));
        lineField.setBackground(this.getForeground());
        lineField.setBorder(OUTER);
        lineField.setEditable(false);

        initLogs();
        updateLogView();
        updateLineView();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(logField);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lineField);
        scrollPane.setVertical...Policy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        ...
    }

    private void initLogs()
    {
        // inits the data in the list
    }

    public void updateLogView()
    {
        logField.setText("");   // reset log field to nothing

        for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++)
        {
            // Append only if the line is visible
            if (logs.get(i).getVisibility())
            {
                // if this isn't the first line, 
                // add a line break before appending
                if (i > 0)
                    logField.append("\n");  

                logField.append(logs.get(i).getLine());
            }
        }       
    }

    public void updateLineView()
    {
        lineField.setText("");  // reset log field to nothing

        for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++)
        {
            // Append only if the line is visible
            if (logs.get(i).getVisibility())
            {
                // if this isn't the first line, 
                // add a line break before appending
                if (i > 0)
                    lineField.append("\n"); 

                lineField.append("" + logs.get(i).getLineNumber());
            }
        }       
    }

    ...

    /***** Main Execution *****/
    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried putting both text fields in the viewPort?  Maybe on a panel that gives the line numbers a fraction of the available width?

Comment: I was not aware that a scrollpane could have more than one viewport? I did try to add the `lineField` to the scrollpane viewport by adding `scrollPane.getViewport().add(lineField);` but that eliminated all of the text areas from the window. Looks like there was some kind of an error creating them.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood your comment. I will try and put them on a panel now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: That does work. I'll have to clean it up a little bit in terms of borders and insents, but the scrollbar works and the line numbers populate correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The compenent used to display the line numbers can be added using:

```
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(...);
```

Another option is to use a JTable to display both columns. Using two text areas is really not the best solution.

Comment: Yea I saw in his code he was calling setRowHeaderView, but it wasn't  working the way he needed it, so I suggested two text areas.  I think the JTable might be the best solution.

Comment: I actually did move to a JTable and it works much better. The problem I am having now is the table rows are not updating when I call `fireTableCellUpdated(0, getRowCount());` Not sure exactly why yet.

Comment: @njozwiak, I see two problems. First, the parameters should be (row, column). You are providing (row, row). Second, the parameters are zero based so the last cell is actually getRowCount() - 1.