# How do I have line numbers in my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea

Is it possible to display line numbers in a `JTextArea`? Please advise me how to write code in JApplet.

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Java-ee (despite being an applet, presumably) 2) *"If you have any example Program?"*  I have plenty, what about them?  But please don't ask for code.  People provide code if they have time (and feel like it). 3) *"Thanks Advance...."*  Please leave noise like 'thanks' out of questions, and fix that stuck '.' key. 4) *"..how to write code in JApplet."*  Exactly the same way you would in a frame - applets have nothing to do with the problem. 5) Applets are an advanced topic, that you think 'applet' has any bearing on this suggests you are not very experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This may be useful for you](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/915-how-add-line-numbers-your-jtextarea.html)  and [This stackoverflow question also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618136/java-jtextarea-line-numbers)

Answer (score 8):

Use this
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/